# signal types and wire types

Tags: signal, wire, differential, coax, manchester-coding

I am trying to understand the selection criterion for choosing between a signal types and wire type out of the following:

Signal types:

1. Gnd reference uni-polar signal
2. Gnd reference bi-polar signal
3. Differential signal
4. Balanced signal
5. Encoded signal eg., Manchester encoded

Wire types:

1. Single core wire
2. Multi-core wire
3. Braided wire
4. Flexible wire
5. Co-axial wire
6. Shielded wire
7. Twisted-pair wires

I want to understand when to use which signal type and which wire type when designing any electronic system? Are there any guidelines for these selection?

Comment: Often the choice can be made from the availability of appropriate ICs. For example you can not find a serializer IC with a single ended 500MHz TTL/CMOS output. This output will be LVDS or PECL or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Gnd reference uni-polar signal
```

normal Signals I would say. they are cheap to generate, cheep to receive. Not generally good for longer distances and higher speeds, you need to prepare to cope with EMI Problems.

```
Gnd reference bi-polar signal
```

hmm, yes in anlog applications maybe, for digital signals the only advantage would be combined with a dc-free code the average potential is equal to GND.

```
Differential signal
```

reduces EMI problems by magnitudes combined with good signal encodings and shields that's the gold standard for least signal distortion ar at least well predictable signal distortion, acceptable impedance, plus good EMI performance

```
Balanced signal
```

You want your differential signal to be balanced. It's part to get the performance you want, also you want the signal to be DC-Free, so your signal does not drift to a point where the receiver is no longer able to detect it without errors

```
Encoded signal eg., Manchester encoded
```

Well all digital signals are encoded somehow. A multi level code like the Manchester Code gives you a improved data rate above a simple 2 level Pulse-Amplitude Modulation (more bits per clock cycle). Multilevel codes are more complex and suffer from higher susceptibility to EMI (signal to Noise ratio of the transmission channel...) But even schemes like QAM64,128,... are already in use. In most cases combined with some error detection and correction stages.

Wire types:

```
Single core wire
```

normally not used for signals, good for GND/Earth connection, Power distribution, with signals you suffer from gnd-loops, at least you want em to be short.

```
Multi-core wire
```

pure multicore without combination of shields and e.g. twisted pairs is good for power distribution and only used for low speed analog stuff or low speed busses. Suffer from all kinds of EMI problems.

With additional technologies these cables can be among the best - ethernet and USB show you can transfer Gigabit/sec

```
Braided wire
```

low resistance GND connection but suffers from parasitic inductance, which e.g. fails to guide high frequency EMI from a shield to Earth. Single Core Wires are much better here

```
Flexible wire
```

more expensive, bit more parasitic inductance

```
Co-axial wire
```

very good for high frequency. Most High speed messurement equipment is connected with Coax

```
Shielded wire
```

Shields are the Multitool for EMI problems, can be combined with almost any form of cable. Shields are a complex topic of their own. desity of the shield, how to connect with the shield,...

Comment: You answer will be better if you provide typical applicability parameters such as voltage, frecuency and cost for each case.

Comment: @Arseniy for every cable type there so many variants on the market plus so many more parameters like non-flammability, mechanical stress, propagation delay skew, crosstalk, allowed variance of impedance,... I don't think I can give any valid rules of thumb according voltage, frecuency and cost